# To find the Largest divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What can be the maximum value of $n$ if,

$$\frac{50!}{6^n}$$is a natural number

Is there a trick to solve it because honestly I have no idea how to do this!

Comment: $6^n=2^n\cdot 3^n$. How many factors of $2$ and $3$ are there in the numbers $1$ to $50$? From the right perspective, you should be able to list them all out without a ton of effort.

Comment: This came in an exam where we had less than a minute for each problem

Comment: So I believe it can be done in an easier way

Comment: Somehow I said that backwards; $3$ is the limiting factor here. But this is sort of a standard method, so I doubt there is a faster way

Comment: try to find $n$ for $\frac{10!}{6^n}$ (without using a calculator) or even with lower numerators. Maybe you will gain some insight.

Comment: Check [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no trick. You will just have to work.

Consider the numbers $1,2,3,\ldots,50$. Then, see, in each of them, which is the highest power of $2$ that divedes them and which is the highest power of $3$ that divides them. For instance, in the case of $3$, you have:

- the numbers $3$, $6$, $12$, $15$, $21$, $24$, $30$, $33$, $39$, $42$, and $48$ are multiples of $3$ but not of $3^2$ ($11$ numbers);
- the numbers $9$, $18$, $36$, and $45$ are multiples of $3^2$, but not of $3^3$ ($4$ numbers);
- the only element of the list which is a multiple of $3^3$ is $27$ ($1$ number).

So, the greatest power of $3$ which divides $50!$ is $11+2\times 4+3\times1=22$.

Now, do the same thing with $2$. The $n$ that you're after will be the smallest of the two numbers (actually, it will have to be $22$).

Comment: Can you please elaborate the step where you did the arithmetic part(I don't    uderstand the concept used )

Comment: Ok I understand what you did

Answer (score 2):

You need to realize that you have to find the highest power of $3$ dividing $50!$ as $3$ is the largest prime factor of $6.$

In general, the highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $N!$ is given by:

$$s_p(N!) = \left \lfloor \frac{N}{p} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{N}{p^2} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{N}{p^3} \right \rfloor + \cdots$$

Therefore the value of n is $$n = \left \lfloor \frac{50}{3} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{50}{3^2} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{50}{3^3} \right \rfloor + 0= 16 + 5 + 1 = 22.$$